# How to use Mysql and MongoDB on same NodeJs server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, rest

I have a REST API in NodeJS and Express JS. Here's the basic thing what I need to implement. There's a database in mysql and my node js server read the database in some specific conditions and need to make a log in MongoDB server. It is the architecture and it can't be changed. So is it possible to use both MySQL and MongoDB in same NodeJs server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's 100% possible, they use completely different ports and do not care about each other.

The server isn't a 'nodejs' server, it's a server that's running nodejs, and you can install anything you want on the server.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. And also I searched a lot and still no answer. Do you have some code snippet or link which showing the way.

Comment: There's no code snippet just install them on the server

Answer (score 1):

either you can directly write following mongodb and mysql database connection code in youe **app.js** *(starter file)* file

or you can write is separate files for mongo and mysql connection as follows:

**step 1.** create file named as **mongodb_con.js**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
.then(sucess => {
    console.log("connected with mongo server...")
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("error while connecting to database...")
})
```

**step 2.** create file named as **mysql_con.js**

```
const mysql = require("mysql")

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost", //your hostname
user: "root",      //your username
password: "root",  //your password 
database: "detabase_name" //your database name
})

con.connect((error) => {
if (!error) {
    console.log("connected with sql server")
}
else {
    console.log("Error in Making Connection...", error)
}
})
```

**step 3.** in final stepjust import both file in **app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('./mongodb_con.js')
require('./mysql_con.js')
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```